# How do I enable Javascript to function properly in GeckoFX?

Tags: javascript, geckofx

I've started to use GeckoFX but I got a major issue with javascript:void(0) that acts as anchor which lets JS to pop new window and load url. How do I tell browser to do this INSIDE the geckobrowser component? RIght now, when I click it..nothing happens.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To handle a new browser window, you need to handle the CreateWindow event of the GeckoWebBrowser. Then you open a new form with a web browser control, and set e.WebBrowser to that control:

```
private void webBrowser_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e) {
  BrowserForm frm = new BrowserForm();
  e.WebBrowser = frm.WebBrowser;
  frm.Show();
}
```